# style.css not found on this server

Tags: php, html, css, http-status-code-404

I'm working on a php-project that i just uploaded to my server online : [see my project](http://edeezine.com/emmanuel_wiedenhoff/Lokisalle/index.php)

On localhost everything seems fine, but when uploaded to server, there is no styling. The file style.css is present on the ftp.server and when inspecting the element both in Chrome and FF they give the same message in the style editor :

```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head>
> <title>404 Not Found</title> </head><body> <h1>Not Found</h1> <p>The
> requested URL /Lokisalle/css/style.css was not found on this
> server.</p> </body></html>
```

The link in the `<head>` tag is also looking fine to me...

Any hints ?

Many thanks.

Comment: The error message is your hint. You need to use a relative path (no leading "/" before "Lokisalle")

Comment: thanks @JosefEngelfrost I managed to get my styling back partly (need to crawl the whole code to make some fixes), i used the define("site_root", "Lokisalle") and apparently that was what was messing it up....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your URLS carefully. The URL you have used for your style sheet contains a leading `/`, but your web site is not in the web root, so the browser is looking in the wrong place.

The root of your site is in the `Lokisalle` folder, so use a path relative to that

Remove the `/Lokisalle` here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Lokisalle/css/style.css"> 
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^ take this out.
```

Use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Lokisalle/css/style.css">
```

with

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

and it works.